"Ill-formed syntax: (define (expmod a num num) ((exptmod num) a num))" in Scheme
I am learning SICP up to chapter 2.2.1 now. I have the following code:
(define (modular n op)
  (lambda (a b)
    (modulo (op a b) n)))
(define (exptmod p)
  (let ((mod* (modular p *)))
    (define (square x)
      (mod* x x))
    (define (em base exponent)
      ;; from SICP fast-expt.
      (cond ((= exponent 0) 1)
            ((even? exponent) (square (em base (/ exponent 2))))
            (else (mod* base (em base (- exponent 1)))))) ; not use * directly.
    em))

(define (fermat-test n)
  (define (expmod a num num) 
    ((exptmod num) a num))
  (define (try-it a)
    ; (= ((exptmod n) a n) a))
    (= (expmod a n n) a))
  (try-it (+ 1 (random (- n 1)))))
(fermat-test 2)

It will throw error "Ill-formed syntax: (define (expmod a num num) ((exptmod num) a num))".
But if I just replace the expression by the expression to substitute, it works fine outputing #t:
(define (modular n op)
  (lambda (a b)
    (modulo (op a b) n)))
(define (exptmod p)
  (let ((mod* (modular p *)))
    (define (square x)
      (mod* x x))
    (define (em base exponent)
      ;; from SICP fast-expt.
      (cond ((= exponent 0) 1)
            ((even? exponent) (square (em base (/ exponent 2))))
            (else (mod* base (em base (- exponent 1)))))) ; not use * directly.
    em))

(define (fermat-test n)
  ; (define (expmod a num num) 
  ;   ((exptmod num) a num))
  (define (try-it a)
    (= ((exptmod n) a n) a))
    ; (= (expmod a n n) a))
  (try-it (+ 1 (random (- n 1)))))
(fermat-test 2)

Could someone tell me the reasons?

(define (expmod a num num) ;... has two parameters that share the same name. If you called (expmod 1 2 3) what is the value of num? That is why the definition is ill-formed.
